# Android: attempting to start OpenGL activity, app crashes

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-activity, crash

I'm a newbie to Android development. Please bear with me if this question is trivial.

I have a main activity which contains a button:

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/single_player"
     style="@style/ButtonTheme"
     android:text="Single Player"
     android:visibility="visible"
     android:onClick="OpenGameActivity" />
```

and a method inside the main activity for the button to route to:

```
public void OpenGameActivity()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Now, the GameActivity.class is an activity for creating a GLSurfaceView:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class GameActivity extends Activity {
    private GLSurfaceView GridView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create a GLSurfaceView instance and set it
        // as the ContentView for this Activity.
        GridView = new GameView(this);
        setContentView(GridView);
    }
```

GameView is a simple implementation of GLSurfaceView which creates GameRender, a simple implementation of GLSurfaceView.Renderer. I set up the Activity, SurfaceView, and Renderer all based on the guide at http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/environment.html
The renderer looks like this:

```
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

public class GameRender implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {


    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
        // Redraw background color
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl10, javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig eglConfig) {
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl10, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }
}
```

the problem is, every time I click the button from my Android phone which should start the new activity, the app crashes. What am I doing wrong?

I did my research before posting this, so for clarification I DID add the new activity to the manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name=".GameActivity"
                android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                    android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

Comment: What error are u getting?.Post logcat trace

Comment: I don't get an error. Logcat literally does nothing when the button is pressed, and the app just crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

`public void OpenGameActivity()`

to

`public void OpenGameActivity(View view)`

If you're referring a function from XML I think you need to accept a View parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Here there is no instance for Object, change your code like this

```
GridView gridview = new GameView(this);
setContentView(gridview );
```